# Prove that an infinte ring with identity must have an infinite number of non-invertible elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The problem is to prove that an infinte ring $K$ with identity can not contain a finite number $n \ge 1$ of non-invertible elements.

The hint advices to use a proof by contradiction. Assume that $N = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ is the set of all non-invertible elements of $K$ without $0$. A map $p_x: a_i \to xa_i$ is a bijection $N \to N$, $\forall x \in K \setminus(N \cup{0})$. And the kernel of the map $p: x \to p_x$ is infinite.

I wanted to show that in this case the map $p$ is an isomorphism from $K \setminus(N \cup{0})$ to a subset $H \subset S_n$ of all permutations on $N$ and therefore $K \setminus(N \cup{0})$ must contain a finite number of elements, but the kernel of $p$ which is a susbset of $K \setminus(N \cup{0})$ has an infinite number of elements by contradition. I could make a mistake, but I see that $p$
is indeed the isomorphism. I'm not able to prove that its kernel has an infinite number of elements. By its kernel I assume $\ker p = \{ x \in K \setminus(N \cup{0})| p_x = e \}$, where $e$ is the identity permutation on $N$, but the author could think of something different. I can only think of $p_1$ where $1$ is an identity element in $K$ .

Comment: Do you mean a finite number of nonzero non-invertible elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $K$ is an infinite ring whose set of nonzero nonunits is finite. Let $N= \{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ be the set of nonzero nonunits. Let $K^{\times} = K\setminus (N\cup\{0\})$ be the group of units of $K$. As noted in the problem, the infinite group $K^{\times}$ acts by left multiplication on the finite set $N$, yielding a permutation representation $p\colon K^{\times}\to S_N\colon x\mapsto p_x$. This representation must have infinite kernel.
If $g_1, g_2, \ldots \in \ker(p)$ are infinitely many distinct elements of this kernel, then
$$A = \{g_2-g_1, g_3-g_1, g_4-g_1\ldots\}$$
is an infinite set of distinct nonzero
elements which annihilate $N$ from the left.
(That is, $(g_i-g_1)a_j = g_ia_j-g_1a_j = a_j-a_j = 0$ for all $i, j$.) But the only nonzero elements of $K$ that can annihilate nonzero elements of $K$ lie in $N$, so we are led to the conclusion that the infinite set $A$ is a subset of the finite set $N$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

**Challenge:** "Prove that an infinte ring with identity must have an infinite number of non-invertible elements."

**Answer:** If $K$ is an infinite field it follows every element in $K-0$ is invertible. The only non-invertible element is $0$, hence this is not true in general.